# How to I call multiple VBA functions in one event?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have several functions that I would like to have fire "OnLoad", I understand how I could create one function that in turn calls all other functions.  Unfortunately I pass several values through to each function, so attempting to send all of those to one function and in turn forward the correct ones to each function seems like a poor way to resolve my dilemma.

So I would like to simply just call all functions OnLoad though I can't seem to find anywhere online if it is possible. I have theorized that I could create 4 hidden controls, then create an Onload macro that calls the OnClick events for each control, but that seems like a very odd way to accomplish what I am trying to do.

Does anyone have any experience with this?  Is there a more effective way to do what I am looking to do?

Comment: If you know the answer, either answer the question yourself or delete it.  Probably the latter.

Comment: Since the purpose of me posting was because I wasn't able to find this simple answer online I will probably leave it here, though I have written down the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm an idiot, 5 seconds after posting this I realized I could just use RunCode in that macro to do what I want. Hopefully this may be useful to someone else in the future.

Comment: If you're going this direction that's fine, but this answer won't help future readers too much without some sample code.